# Subversion diff including only my changes to file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, diff, branching-and-merging

Consider file X in branch1 and the same file X in branch2.

1. Person A changes file X in branch1
2. Person B changes file X in branch1.

I want to apply changes made only by person B in file X in branch1 to file X in branch2. How can I do that? If it is not possible, how do I diff those two files and see changes applied only by person B?

I am using TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform your diff, only include the revision(s) that Person B committed.

If A & B have made changes to the same lines and their commits are interleaved, this won't work. If their changes are mutually exclusive, when you apply a diff consisting **only** of revisions made by B, then A's changes won't be included.

If B makes a change after A, B's commit *does not* "contain changes introduced by A" **unless** B changes one or more of the lines lines A changed. If A changed lines 1-10 and B changed lines 40-50, the diff of B's revision contains **only** the changes to lines 40-50.

If this is a frequent occurrence, you need to make smaller commits, or have your users working in private branches.

Comment: Could you expand your answer please? Does it apply to scenario when B make changes to X (branch1), A make changes to X (branch1), B make changes to X (branch1)? Now I want to merge (or diff at least) to branch2 only changes made by B. Please note that after B second commit file X contains changes introducted by A.